# Python: Dynamically generating attributes from a list

Tags: python, metaclass, python-descriptors

I want to be able to dynamically generate attributes of a class from a list or dictionary.  The idea is that I can define a list of attributes, and then be able to access those attributes using `my_class.my_attribute`

For example:

```
class Campaign(metaclass=MetaCampaign):
    _LABELS = ['campaign_type', 'match_type', 'audience_type'] # <-- my list of attributes
    
    for label in _LABELS:
        setattr(cls, label, LabelDescriptor(label))
    
    def __init__(self, campaign_protobuf, labels)
        self._proto = campaign_protobuf
        self._init_labels(labels_dict)
        
    def _init_labels(self, labels_dict):
        # magic...
```

This obviously won't work because `cls` doesn't exist, but I'd like:

```
my_campaign = Campaign(campaign, label_dict)
print(my_campaign.campaign_type)
```

to return the value `campaign_type` for the `campaign`.  This is obviously a little complicated, as `campaign_type` is actually a `Descriptor` and does a bit of work to retrieve a value from a base `Label` object.

---

**The Descriptor:**

```
class DescriptorProperty(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.data[instance] = value


class LabelTypeDescriptor(DescriptorProperty):
    """A descriptor that returns the relevant metadata from the label"""
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        super(MetaTypeLabel, self).__init__()
        self.cached_data = WeakKeyDictionary()
        # Regex pattern to look in the label:
        #       r'label_type:ThingToReturn'
        self.pattern = f"{pattern}:(.*)"

    def __get__(self, instance, owner, refresh=False):
        # In order to balance computational speed with memory usage, we cache label values
        # when they are first accessed.        
        if self.cached_data.get(instance, None) is None or refresh:
            ctype = re.search(self.pattern, self.data[instance].name) # <-- does a regex search on the label name (e.g. campaign_type:Primary)
            if ctype is None:
                ctype = False
            else:
                ctype = ctype.group(1)
            self.cached_data[instance] = ctype
        return self.cached_data[instance]
```

This enables me to easily access the value of a label, and if the label is of a type that I care about, it will return the relevant value, otherwise it will return `False`.

---

**The Label Object:**

```
class Label(Proto):
    _FIELDS = ['id', 'name']
    _PROTO_NAME = 'label'
    #  We define what labels can pull metadata directly through a property
    campaign_type = LabelTypeDescriptor('campaign_type')
    match_type = LabelTypeDescriptor('match_type')
    audience_type = LabelTypeDescriptor('audience_type')

    def __init__(self, proto, **kwargs):
        self._proto = proto
        self._set_default_property_values(self)  # <-- the 'self' is intentional here, in the campaign object a label would be passed instead.

    def _set_default_property_values(self, proto_wrapper):
        props = [key for (key, obj) in self.__class__.__dict__.items() if isinstance(obj, DescriptorProperty)]
        for prop in props:
            setattr(self, prop, proto_wrapper)
```

So if I have a protobuf label object stored in my Label (which is basically just a wrapper) which looks like this:

```
resource_name: "customers/12345/labels/67890"
id {
  value: 67890
}
name {
  value: "campaign_type:Primary"
}
```

Then `my_label.campaign_type` would return `Primary`, and similarly `my_label.match_type` would return `False`

---

The reason being is that I'm creating a number of classes that are all labelled in the same way, and may have a lot of labels.  Currently this all works as described, but I'd like to be able to define the attributes more dynamically as they all basically follow the same type of pattern.  So instead of :

```
    campaign_type = LabelTypeDescriptor('campaign_type')
    match_type = LabelTypeDescriptor('match_type')
    audience_type = LabelTypeDescriptor('audience_type')
    ... # (many more labels)
```

I simply have:  `_LABELS = ['campaign_type', 'match_type', 'audience_type', ... many more labels]` and then have some loop that creates the attributes.

In turn I can cascade a similar approach through to my other classes, so that while a `Campaign` object may hold a `Label` object, I can access the value of the label simply by `my_campaign.campaign_type`.  If the campaign does not have a label of the appropriate type, it will simply return `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `cls` does not exist when the class body is run, you can set the attributes by simply setting then in the dictionary returned by `locals()` inside the class body:

```
class Campaign(metaclass=MetaCampaign):
    _LABELS = ['campaign_type', 'match_type', 'audience_type'] # <-- my list of attributes
    
    for label in _LABELS:
        locals()[label] = label, LabelDescriptor(label)
    del label  # so you don't get a spurious "label" attribute in your class
```

---

Other than that you can use a metaclass, yes, but also a `__init_suclass__` on a base class. Less metaclasses mean less "moving parts" that can behave in strange ways in your system.

So, say your `Proto` class is the base for all others that need this feature:

```py
class Proto:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwd):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwd)
        for label in cls._LABELS:
            setattr(cls, label, LabelDescriptor(label))
    ...
```

I had taken a look at your Descriptors and code there - if they ar already working, I'd say they are all right.

I can comment that it is more usual to store descriptor-related data in the instance's `__dict__` itself, instead of creating the `data` and `cached_data`in the descriptor itself - so one don't need to care about weakrefs - but both approaches work (just this week, I had implemented a descriptor in this way, even though I usually go for the instance's `__dict__`)

Comment: How would I go about storing the descriptor-related data in the instance's __dict__?

Comment: @QuinRiva : just like people do with properties, one might just prepend a `_` to the descriptor name and use setattr/getattr normally: getattr(instance, "_" + self.name) on the getter, and samething on setter. A longer prefix can keep the instance's dict cleaner, though  - instead of `_`, maybe use `_labeltype_` as prefix. But also, one can use `instance.__dict__` directly instead of get/setattr - and on that case, the stored property can have the same name as the descriptor itself. `instance.__dict__[self.name] = value`.

Comment: I basically have everything working now __except__ a single check in one of my descriptors: ```isinstance(self.data[instance], Proto)```.  For some reason this always returns false.  If I try checking this :
```print(isinstance(campaigns['customers/12345/campaigns/67890'].campaign_type, Label))``` returns ```False```
But 
```print(type(campaigns['customers/12345/campaigns/67890'].campaign_type))```
returns  
```<class '__main__.Label'>```.  
No idea what's going on here.

Comment: Nevermind, I have it working now - I suspect it was just a namespace issue with my testing environment.  I reset the Jupyter kernel and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `classmethod` that will initialize these attributes, and call this method after the class declaration:

```py
class Campaign(metaclass=MetaCampaign):
    _LABELS = ['campaign_type', 'match_type', 'audience_type'] # <-- my list of attributes
    
    @classmethod
    def _init_class(cls):
       for label in cls._LABELS:
        setattr(cls, label, LabelDescriptor(label))
# After the class has been declared, initialize the attributes
Campaign._init_class()
```

Comment: Actually, since Python 3.6, there is a special method defined in the language specification itself that will run automatically when the class is created. It is the same thing you had written, but the method should be named `__init_subclass__`  on a baseclass- it will then be called by Python on sub-class creation.